# Iceland in high season: What to prebook?

Tags: bookings, sightseeing, iceland

We will be traveling in Iceland around the complete island for roughly three weeks.

What excursion and sights should one prebook because they tend to be full if booked spontaneously on the day? We have already prebooked the hotels, so that is not my question.

I found at least the [Blue Lagoon](https://www.bluelagoon.com/) needs to be prebooked.

How about whale-watching from Húsavík? Is that something you can do spontaneously?

Comment: Do not bother with the Blue Lagoon, certainly not if you have to pre-book. Overpriced and if you hit the same kind of weather I did, tepid and uninspiring. (If you feel you need to go, make sure you do on a day with good weather but I'd say give it a miss, overpriced for everything.)

Comment: This may just be a question of balancing your wishes to specifically do things versus your desire to be able to be spontaneous.  In the high season, it makes sense to err on the side of caution and to not book things.  In the shoulder season, flexibility can be your friend (as it was with us booking iceberg and puffin-watching tours in Newfoundland on a rare perfect May sunny day).

Comment: I would say all accommodation and car rental. Most tours require 24-48 hours notice. It’s worth noting that Iceland’s tourist infrastructure is vastly over capacity so you should be prepared for lots of disappointment if you try to do things spontaneously.